# Как в массив записать несколько url адресов

Tags: php, массивы, yii2, url

Здравствуйте, мне нужно записать в массив несколько url адресов, чтобы на разных страницах выводить разный sidebar.Страниц будет очень много.На данный момент мой код выглядит так:

```
<?php 
    $sidebarservice = Yii::$app->request->url == '/page/estetic';
    $sidebarortopedic = Yii::$app->request->url == '/page/ortopedic';
?>

<div class="content content-service">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
        <?php if (!$sidebarortopedic) : ?>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <?php echo $this->render('/site/sidebar-service') ?>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if(!$sidebarservice): ?>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                <?php echo $this->render('/site/sidebar-ortopedic') ?>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <div class="col-sm-9 textt">
            <?php echo $model->body ?>
        </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ну если я правильно понял вопрос, то как-то так:

```
<?php 
$sidebarUrlArray=['/page/estetic' => '/site/sidebar-service',
'/page/ortopedic'=>'/site/sidebar-ortopedic','...'=>'...'];

if array_key_exists(Yii::$app->request->url, $sidebarUrlArray) {
    unset($sidebarUrlArray[Yii::$app->request->url]);
}

?>

<div class="content content-service">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <?php foreach ($sidebarUrlArray as $k=>$v) {?>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <?php echo $this->render($v) ?>
                </div>
            <?php }; ?>
            <div class="col-sm-9 textt">
            <?php echo $model->body ?>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```